# How to use Zend_Validate twice

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-validate

I'm using Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists and I would like to validate my Zend_Form against two fields in DB, sample code:

```
    $phone_1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone_1');
    $phone_1->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
                            array(
                                'field' => 'phone_1',
                                'table' => 'customer',
                    )))
            ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
                            array(
                                'field' => 'phone_2',
                                'table' => 'customer',
                    )));
```

Can I accomplish this?

Comment: should work, have you tried it? What are the results? do all of your records have 2 phone numbers? If not there will be an issue.

Comment: As I see from `Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract` `field` value supposed to be string and not filtered anywhere for containing of any invalid chars. So you can try to use `'field' => 'phone_1, phone_2'` – it should work too.

Comment: Yeah @RockyFord I've tried and with this sample it doesn't validate anymore, even the 1st. Not all of records will have 2 numbers, some will just have 1 and NULL as 2nd.

Comment: @zeliboba this way didn't worked too. I got this message: "Unknown column 'table.phone_1, phone2' in 'field list'".

Comment: What issue you're talking about @RockyFord? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: If every record does not have 2 phone numbers the second validator can't work. Probably you don't need the second validator, it really doesn't matter if a record has 2 phone numbers as long as it has one.

Comment: Understood @RockyFord... but a NULL field can be validated, isn't?
I would like to check if the input value exists in both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create validation chain](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/using-multiple-validators-of-the-same-type-on-a-single-field-tp658340p658343.html)

```
$chain = new Zend_Validate();
$foo   = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(...);
$bar   = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(...);
$chain->addValidator($foo)
      ->addValidator($bar);

$element->addValidator($chain);
```

**UPDATE @Bob Kruithof**

Quick and dirty sample using ZF 1.12.3. All code samples and line numbers are from ZF 1.12.3

```
<?php

$aPaths = array(
    'path/to/zf'
);

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $aPaths));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('testSO');

$chain = new Zend_Validate();
$bar = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^Test/');
$baz = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/Valid$/');
$chain->addValidator($bar)
      ->addValidator($baz);

$element->addValidator($chain); 

echo PHP_VERSION . ', ' . Zend_Version::getLatest() . PHP_EOL;

var_dump($element->isValid('Test'));
var_dump($element->isValid('Valid'));
var_dump($element->isValid('Test Valid'));

/* output
5.3.8, 1.12.3
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
*/

?>
```

Why this works: `Zend_Form_Element.php` lines 1144 - 1168 sets validators either by `Zend_Validate` object or by string. You are right - if validators are used with name, not as chain, then as a result one would have single validator. But in result we have:

```
$this->_validators[$name] = $validator;
/* debugger info:
    $name --> (string) Zend_Validate
    $validator --> Zend_Validate object {
  _validators => array(2) (
    [0] => array(2) (
      [instance] => Zend_Validate_Regex object {
      }
      [breakChainOnFailure] => (bool) false
    )
    [1] => array(2) (
      [instance] => Zend_Validate_Regex object {
      }
      [breakChainOnFailure] => (bool) false
    )
  )
  _messages => array(0)
  _errors => array(0)
  zfBreakChainOnFailure => (bool) false
}
*/

public function addValidator($validator, $breakChainOnFailure = false, $options = array())
    {
        if ($validator instanceof Zend_Validate_Interface) {
            $name = get_class($validator);

            if (!isset($validator->zfBreakChainOnFailure)) {
                $validator->zfBreakChainOnFailure = $breakChainOnFailure;
            }
        } elseif (is_string($validator)) {
            $name      = $validator;
            $validator = array(
                'validator' => $validator,
                'breakChainOnFailure' => $breakChainOnFailure,
                'options'             => $options,
            );
        } else {
            require_once 'Zend/Form/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Form_Exception('Invalid validator provided to addValidator; must be string or Zend_Validate_Interface');
        }


        $this->_validators[$name] = $validator;

        return $this;
    }
```

When we call `$element->isValid())` it iterates over all validators inside of the chain - check `Zend_Validate.php`, lines 91-110:

```
public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->_messages = array();
        $this->_errors   = array();
        $result = true;
        foreach ($this->_validators as $element) {
            $validator = $element['instance'];
            if ($validator->isValid($value)) {
                continue;
            }
            $result = false;
            $messages = $validator->getMessages();
            $this->_messages = array_merge($this->_messages, $messages);
            $this->_errors   = array_merge($this->_errors,   array_keys($messages));
            if ($element['breakChainOnFailure']) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

`$this->_validators` is our array of validators:

```
array(2) (
  [0] => array(2) (
    [instance] => Zend_Validate_Regex object {
      _messageTemplates => array(3) (
      )
      _messageVariables => array(1) (
      )
      _pattern => (string) /^Test/
      _value => null
      _messages => array(0)
      _obscureValue => (bool) false
      _errors => array(0)
      _translator => null
      _translatorDisabled => (bool) false
    }
    [breakChainOnFailure] => (bool) false
  )
  [1] => array(2) (
    [instance] => Zend_Validate_Regex object...
```

Comment: This will never work because the validators are stored in an associative array with their classname as key value.

Comment: Actually.. This does work. This solution is more elegant than mine and should be considered the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Validators are stored in association array if they are set by name. There you set them as `Zend_Validate()` object and then you can use them this way. I will update my answer with another example

Comment: You're right, BartekR. Thank you for your detailed explanation. I turned my downvote into an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Zend will add the validators to your form element in an array using the classname of the validator as key. This means that if you want to add the same validator twice but with different specifications, the second validator will overwrite the first.

The most easy, and only slightly messy, way to accomplish adding the same validator is to extend the validator so the second validator receives a different classname:

```
class NewValidator extends Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists { }
```

Now you can use the validator twice:

```
$phone_1->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
                        array(
                            'field' => 'phone_1',
                            'table' => 'customer',
                )))
        ->addValidator(new NewValidator(
                        array(
                            'field' => 'phone_2',
                            'table' => 'customer',
                )));
```

This will do the trick and is a lot faster then creating a custom validator.